# asp.net mvc return url loop forever

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

Angular Routing:

```
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix("!").html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider
    .when('/', { templateUrl: '/home/index', controller: 'homeCtrl' })
    .when('/admin', { templateUrl: '/admin' })
    .when('/cart', { templateUrl: '/shoppingcart/cart' })
    .when('/login', { templateUrl: '/customer/login' })
        .when('/logout', { templateUrl: '/customer/logout' })
   ...
     .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
```

MVC routing:

```
     routes.MapRoute("HomePage",
                 "",
                 new { controller = "Home", action = "Spa" },
                 new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" });
      routes.MapRoute(
      "Default2",
      "{.*}",
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Spa" },
      new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" });

     routes.MapRoute("Logout",
                        "logout/",
                        new { controller = "Customer", action = "Logout" },
                        new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" });
```

CustomerController.cs: (mvc controller)

```
public ActionResult Logout()
        {

                return Redirect("/");   
        }
```

if i try http://domain.com/logout => the page loads forever and not return to homepage. Other pages load just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logout requests are hitting your catch-all route before it can hit the `logout` route definition. Try changing the order of your routes to the following:

```
routes.MapRoute("Logout",
      "logout/",
      new { controller = "Customer", action = "Logout" },
      new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" });    

routes.MapRoute("HomePage",
      "",
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Spa" },
      new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" });

routes.MapRoute(
      "Default2",
      "{.*}",
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Spa" },
      new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" });
```

Also for debugging routes, Phil Haack's route debugger is excellent.
You can find the Nuget package here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/routedebugger/